# How to find convergence radius and convergence range of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I can not find the general term of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$ as $a_{2n}$.

I think $a_{2n}$ can be $\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$. If so, how can i find the next term of the series?

Is the next term equal to $a_{2n+1}$ or $a_{2(n+1)}=a_{2n+2}$?

Which one is true?

Comment: @metamorphy Oh, yeah. Sorry for the mistype.

Answer (score 1):

No mate, here$$a_n =\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$$
Actually the given series is the expansion of $\cos x -1$

Comment: So, the general term of this power series is not based on $a_{2n}$, right?

Comment: Put $x^2=y$ then compute..it will give the  desired form